# Kerning of Chinese characters interacts with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, kerning, xecjk, chinese

I have a problem with Chinese punctuation. In some situations the dot appears on a separate line. I have been able to track the problem down to hyperref:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xeCJK}


\setCJKmainfont[Scale=MatchUppercase,
                Path=../fonts/]{SourceHanSerifSC-Regular}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\xeCJKsetup{PunctStyle=CCT}


\begin{document}


最近的更多有关合并的构成的标记和大量的过度分度分析请参~考 Fabregas et al. （2016）。

最近的更多有关合并的构成的标记和大量的过度分度分析请参~考 \href{x}{Fabregas et al. （2016）}。

参考 \href{x}{Fabregas et al. （2016）}。

\end{document}
```

This results in:
[image]

If there is just text with Chinese brackets, the dot is attached to the bracket, but if there is the text with `href` around it, the dot is kept separate and may end up on a separate line. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: What happens if you change `{Fabregas et al. （2016）}` to either `{Fabregas et al.\ (20160}` or `{Fabregas et al., 2016}`? (I'm afraid I can't try out your code as my system doesn't feature the `SourceHanSerifSC-Regular` font.)

Comment: @Mico The font is [free for download](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-serif/tree/release)

Comment: try `\href{x}{Fabregas et al. （2016）\nobreak}。`

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that this hyperref wrapping is added by a biblatex/hyperref combination. I simplified this to get a MWE. Shall I put the biblatex stuff back in into the example?

Comment: @mico I could go for another font, but I do not know which one is installed on all systems.

Comment: it should be unproblematic if you add the \nobreak to the biblatex output.

Comment: @StefanMüller, you can use `fandolSong`.

Comment: The year field value, `2016` appears to be surrounded by "smart" parentheses that automatically insert some space. That may be ok for other usages, but appears to get in the way of spacing after the href "wrapper" ends. I would replace the closing "smart" parenthesis with a regular parenthesis; that seems to do the trick on my system (MacOS 10.15.5, MacTeX2020).

Comment: These parenthesis are Chinese parenthesis. Took me pains to get them into the BibTeX citations. They have to be there. In some font configurations they take a square space like all other Chinese characters.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think the kerning between the Chinese bracket and the Chinese dot is special. My problem is not just to avoid the linebreak. They should be closer together, but this is blocked because the wrapping by hyperref.

Comment: the link inserts a \special. This prevents kerning and it prevents an inter glyph code from xecjk. What ever spacing you want here. you will have to insert it manually.

Comment: @StefanMüller You can use `\IfFontExistsTF` to load a font if and only if it’s available, with a fallback if it’s not.

Comment: @StefanMüller While no font is available on *all* systems, [these CJK fonts are downloadable from CTAN.](https://www.ctan.org/topic/font-cjk) You might also insert a link to the repository of a free font, or even include the font itself.